# Does PHP compile XPath

Tags: php, xpath, simplexml, domdocument

Can anyone tell me if and when PHP compiles XPath expressions? It would be useful to know for both simpleXML and DOMDocument classes. I also want to know where the compiled XPath is stored.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I imagine it will be "whatever libxml2 does", since that's what all PHP's XML functionality is built on top of. As such, [the libxml homepage](http://www.xmlsoft.org/) is probably a good starting point for research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP's XML functionality is all built on top of [the `libxml2` library](http://www.xmlsoft.org/), so part of the answer will depend on how that library works, and part on how exactly PHP uses it.

Starting with SimpleXML, we can find the implementation of `SimpleXMLElement->xpath()` in [ext/simplexml/simplexml.c](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/simplexml/simplexml.c#L1285). Skipping over some internal housekeeping, checking parameter types, etc, the first interesting line we find is this:

```
if (!sxe->xpath) {
    sxe->xpath = xmlXPathNewContext((xmlDocPtr) sxe->document->ptr);
}
```

So repeated XPath expressions on the same `SimpleXMLElement` will use the same "XPath context", but it won't be shared with other instances. Further down, we find where this is used:

```
retval = xmlXPathEval((xmlChar *)query, sxe->xpath);
```

So PHP is calling a libxml function `xmlXPathEval` which just takes a string and a context, and evaluates it immediately. The [libxml manual for xmlXPathEval`](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xpath.html#xmlXPathEval) says:

> Evaluate the XPath Location Path in the given context.
>
> Returns:  the xmlXPathObjectPtr resulting from the evaluation or NULL. the caller has to free the object.

And indeed, PHP frees that result at the end of the method:

```
xmlXPathFreeObject(retval);
```

So, in SimpleXML at least, there is no separate compilation step, and nothing is stored between calls to the method.

The DOM version is a bit more complicated, because it has a user-visible object representing the XPath context, which is defined in [`/ext/dom/xpath.c`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/dom/xpath.c). Firstly, the constructor sets up the context, as you might expect:

```
PHP_METHOD(domxpath, __construct)
{
    # ...
    ctx = xmlXPathNewContext(docp);
```

It then does some magic to reuse this context where possible, but we haven't compiled any *XPath* yet, this is just the *context*, i.e. the "current node" to compare expressions against. The definitions for both `->eval()` or `->query()` use the same C implementation, `php_xpath_eval`. This checks some internal state is correct, and then calls:

```
xpathobjp = xmlXPathEvalExpression((xmlChar *) expr, ctxp);
```

That's a different function, so we can [look it up in libxml](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xpath.html#xmlXPathEvalExpression):

> Function: xmlXPathEvalExpression
>   Alias for xmlXPathEval().

So, it turns out there's no difference after all. Again, it's passed a string, returns a result, and the PHP function frees that result before returning:

```
xmlXPathFreeObject(xpathobjp);
```

So, as before: no explicit compilation, and the only thing stored between calls is the "context" for XPath expressions to run against.

It turns out libxml *does support* some kind of cache, if enabled via [`xmlXPathContextSetCache`](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xpath.html#xmlXPathContextSetCache):

> Creates/frees an object cache on the XPath context. If activates XPath objects (xmlXPathObject) will be cached internally to be reused. @options: 0: This will set the XPath object caching: @value: This will set the maximum number of XPath objects to be cached per slot There are 5 slots for: node-set, string, number, boolean, and misc objects. Use <0 for the default number (100). Other values for @options have currently no effect.

In the case of SimpleXML, this cache would not be useful anyway, as the context is discarded after use; for DOM, it would be more relevant, as the context - and therefore the cache - would live as long as the PHP `DOMXPath` object.

We can [dig into the implementation of `xmlXpathNewContext`](https://github.com/GNOME/libxml2/blob/master/xpath.c#L6117) to see if this cache is enabled or disabled by default:

```
#ifdef XP_DEFAULT_CACHE_ON
    if (xmlXPathContextSetCache(ret, 1, -1, 0) == -1) {
    xmlXPathFreeContext(ret);
    return(NULL);
    }
#endif
```

So it turns out that this is a *compile-time option* - if the `libxml` compiled or loaded into your PHP had this flag set when it was compiled, I believe you will, in the case of DOM XPath, have some degree of caching, *within a single DOMXPath` instance*.

Comment: Hmm, this is very disappointing. Thanks though, that's some great detective work.

Comment: @Kaan It bugged me that I'd just assumed something, so I dug one step further, and have added some maybe slightly better news.

Comment: Ok, so since you've edited your answer this is slightly less disappointing. Still disappointing though. I was hoping that some compiled code would live across multiple executions. Now I will probably have to alter my code simply to make use of the cache within a single execution.